How to make ID with specified length with hashlib?
I need unique ID's to make it primary key in database and use it for join tables.
How to make ID with length I need?
For example my string:
'827263877-13969916-1800-1-0.0'

I use this code to make ID:
def make_unique_id(*args):
    data = '-'.join(str(args))
    id = hashlib.md5(data.encode('ascii')).hexdigest()
    id_int = int(id, 32)
    return id_int

Result:
test_id_digest: '051fbd93807b21c48f7a579dbd48e13c'
test_id_final_int: 6810946243257077380510446529265852732

How can I generate integer ID with 10 numbers length?

What properties should your id have? Is it required to be unique? It can't be; what percentage of collisions are you willing to accept? Should it be reversible into the original value? It can't be.

I need make unique ID to make it primary key in database and use it for join.

You don’t know why you don’t get unique numbers? If you shorten a ~24 digit number to 10 digits, you cannot fit all 10^24 values into the possible 10^10 values.

I figured out why I don't get complete unique ID's. I make wrong '_'.join() for values.

import hashlib
all_values = '827263877-13969916-1800-1-0.0'
test_id_digest = hashlib.md5(all_values.encode('ascii')).hexdigest()
test_id_final_int = int(test_id_digest[:10], 16)
test_id_final_int = test_id_final_int % (10**10)
print("test_id_final_int:", test_id_final_int)


Feeding a 10 character hex value into int won't (always) produce a 10 digit number.

we can aslo use modulo operator (%) with large number to trim integer to 10 digits

You don't need the [:10] slice then either.

as we are already using the modulo operator to ensure a 10-digit result there is  no need to take a slice of hash value

This code working test_id_final_int % (10**10), make there's no need to make slice. I think I some cases this code can make duplicated ID's.

but it can potentially lead to collision
